# how to change certain letters in a python string to lowercase or uppercase with indexing

Tags: python

hey guys im currently trying to finish up a hw assignment for my python class, im having trouble with one question and i feel like im close but i cant quite get it, all i need to do is take letters from a file and change the letters in index [64:90] to lowercase letters but i cant quite figure it out, it prints the letters but not how it should if you need any more info about it let me know :)
im just going to link my code file or something cause this website is too confusing to format code
so here lol https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RyWnNlMk6QED81Zlb01sjARThsuIie4Z

Comment: please post the full code, properly indented as well as how you open the file and call this function. SO formats code with 4 spaces, so please indent yours properly so it is readable

Comment: Not sure why you're doing a join at the end. You can modify your string in place, using the function you provided. `dnasequence[64:90] = dnasequence[64:90].upper()` will do the trick\

Comment: This: `if introns [64:90] == introns.upper():`  is by definition False.  A part of a list can _NEVER_ be equal to the full lists, if the part smaller then the full list .... beside thatn, `introns` is at maximum of length 90-64 = 26  .. so the slice of `introns [64:90]` is always **empty**!  Please at least **try** to solve your assignment instead of pasting ill formatted nonsense code...

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#3)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Ive added a link to my python file, hope that works

Comment: @GunnarSetterstrom don't use external sites for code; add it directly into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only a couple of things you need to do, and I think you can already do these, just need to piece them all together:

1. Open the file
2. Read it into a string
3. Convert the desired characters to lowercase
4. Write the full string to the file again (overriding the old content).

So, those steps as code would look something like:

```
with open('the_file.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()
s = s[:64] + s[64:90].lower() + s[90:]
with open('the_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```